# Is there any repository of OSRM files already processed?

Tags: osrm

I'm building the entire world of OSRM in one instance.
Is a process that is taking hours to process and I would like to know if there is some repository where I can download the data already processed, saving tons of very expensive machines processing the planet-latest.osm.pbf

If doesn't exists, or there is some reason nobody has thought about it, or if you know how to speedup this process it'll be very welcome.

I'm currently using a N1-highmem-32 (200GB mem + 32 Cores + 700GB SSD (100GB SWAP)) 15 hours running docker public image and still in the step (Find segregated edges in node-based graph)

Thanks,